# caterpillar plot for cross classified random effects

Tags: r, ggplot2, multilevel-analysis

I have a cross-classified model as the following. I would like to plot the random effects of nonprofit on the industry level to a caterpillar plot. What are the steps? Thanks!

```
M <- lmer(salary ~ 1+education+male+nonprofit+(1+nonprofit|ind)+(1+nonprofit|occ), data, reml=TRUE)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)